# ListView Control - get more items

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listview

I'm trying to find an answer to the above question without much success - perhaps I'm asking the wrong question or taking the wrong approach.

I'm using C#, Asp.Net, however still on version 4 of the framework.

I use a listview control to display a finite number of items. Usually, I would display 10 items and add paging, however I'm looking for a slighly different approach on this occasion.

Like many modern apps, I wan't to add a 'more' button, and simply append to the page items I already have, but I can't see how this is possible. Sure I can go back and get 20 items, instead of 10 then rebind, but after a few clicks (30, 40, 50...) this is likely to become unwieldly and very slow.

I've not done much with Ajax, so it might be an alternative avenue to pursue, but rather than dive right in an get it completely wrong, I'd appreciate some advice on how best to approach it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the question involves database, you can find here how to paginate query result: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx

Can you post some code? Is it right a solution server side ?

Can i suggest to use a Repeater instead of ListView?

Comment: I know how to paginate query result, but what I'm asking isn't pagination - its extending the data rather than replacing it.

Comment: You could get some ideas by searching for "infinite scrolling" in ASP.NET ListViews. Here is a link that provides some interesting references: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9d3cadd3-dc95-4219-9f90-e1aae6ad25c8/infinite-scrolling-with-listview?forum=winappswithcsharp.

Answer (score 0):

You can realize it server side or client side.

Server Side - Suppose to have a

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
private FillList()
{
     //...
}

private int CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = ViewState["CurrentPage"];
            if (obj != null)
                return (int)obj;
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["CurrentPage"] = value;
        }
    }

private void RptBind(int curPage, int pageSize)
{
    rptFoos.DataSource = foos.Skip(pageSize * curPage).Take(pageSize);
    rptFoos.Databind();
}

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CurrentPage += 1;
     RptBind(CurrentPage, 10);
}
```

and the Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptFoos">
    <ItemTeplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblFoo" Text="<%# ((Foo)Container.DataItem).Name %>">
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnNext" Text="Next" OnClick="btnNext_Click">
```

Above code is not tested.

Comment: Once again, this is paging and I'm not looking for paging - I'm looking to extend the datasource rather than replacing it each time - so first time I might show 10 results, the next time 20, the next time 30 and so on.

Comment: You can easily change this code:
`foos.Skip(pageSize * curPage).Take(pageSize);`